# In oracle,does a stored procedure fail to execute further, if another stored procedure (being called inside the first procedure) fails

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

There are two stored procedures - proc_outer() and proc_inner(). proc_inner() is being called through proc_outer() as given below -

```
create procedure proc_outer() as
-- some statements
Begin
-- some statements
proc_inner();
-- update statements;
End proc_outer;
/
```

So the question is - If proc_inner() fails due to run time exception, will proc_outer also fail or will proc_outer continue executing update statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll fail. Have a look at the example:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> create table test (col number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> create or replace procedure proc_inner as
  2    l_div number;
  3  begin
  4    select 1/0 into l_div from dual;
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> create or replace procedure proc_outer as
  2    l_col test.col%type;
  3  begin
  4    update test set col = col + 100;
  5    select col into l_col from test;
  6    dbms_output.put_line('some statements - l_col = ' || l_col);
  7    proc_inner;
  8    update test set col = col + 200;
  9    select col into l_col from test;
 10    dbms_output.put_line('update statements - l_col = ' || l_col);
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec proc_outer
some statements - l_col = 101
BEGIN proc_outer; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.PROC_INNER", line 4
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.PROC_OUTER", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL> select * from test;

       COL
----------
         1

SQL>
```

As you can see, "some statements" were executed, but "update statements" weren't.

Furthermore, even though the first `UPDATE` was successful (`l_col = 101`), the error caused a rollback so the final result in the test table is a starting "`1`".